# iText 7 (v8.0.1) C# - How to add a image to every page of a pdf

Tags: c#, image, pdf, itext7

I would need some help.

I use the 8.01 versioen of iText7.
The pdf I need to work on is not a physical file but are bytes.
The image to apply is an image object.

I have searched a lot and tried several times but to no avail.

I have the working version based on itext5 though.
I need to keep the method signature the same.

```
public static byte[] SignDocument(byte[] pdf, System.Drawing.Image sign, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat format, float x, float y, float width, float height)
{
    PdfReader pdfReader = new PdfReader(pdf);
    MemoryStream outputStream = new MemoryStream();
    PdfStamper pdfStamper = new PdfStamper(pdfReader, outputStream, '1', true);
    pdfStamper.Writer.CloseStream = false;
    for (int pageIndex = 1; pageIndex <= pdfReader.NumberOfPages; pageIndex++)
    {
        PdfContentByte content = pdfStamper.GetOverContent(pageIndex);

        iTextSharp.text.Image signImage = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(sign, format);
        float conversion = 1f / 0.352777778f;

        signImage.SetAbsolutePosition(x * conversion, y * conversion);
        signImage.ScaleToFit(width * conversion, height * conversion);
        content.AddImage(signImage);
    }

    pdfStamper.Close();

    outputStream.Position = 0;
    byte[] signedDocument = outputStream.ToArray();

    outputStream.Close();
    outputStream.Dispose();

    return signedDocument;
}
```

**EDIT**

I was able to achieve the goal but only on the first page and not operating in memory; I create temporary files which I then delete.

```
public static byte[] SignDocument(byte[] pdfBytes, System.Drawing.Image sign, string temporaryPdfPath, float x, float y, float width, float height)
{
    if (!Directory.Exists(temporaryPdfPath))
        Directory.CreateDirectory(temporaryPdfPath);

    string temporaryPdfFromDb = $"TempPdf-{DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyHHmmssffff")}.pdf";
    string temporaryPdfFromDbFullPath = Path.Combine(temporaryPdfPath, temporaryPdfFromDb);

    File.WriteAllBytes(temporaryPdfFromDbFullPath, pdfBytes);
    ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.Create(sign, null, false);

    string temporaryPdfFromDbModified = $"TempPdfModified-{DateTime.Now.ToString("ddMMyyyHHmmssffff")}.pdf";
    string temporaryPdfFromDbModifiedFullPath = Path.Combine(temporaryPdfPath, temporaryPdfFromDbModified);

    PdfWriter pdfWriter = new PdfWriter(temporaryPdfFromDbModifiedFullPath);
    pdfWriter.SetSmartMode(true);

    PdfDocument pdfDoc = new PdfDocument(new PdfReader(temporaryPdfFromDbFullPath), pdfWriter);
    Document document = new Document(pdfDoc);

    iText.Layout.Element.Image image = new iText.Layout.Element.Image(data);

    float conversion = 1f / 0.352777778f;

    image.SetFixedPosition(x * conversion, y * conversion);
    image.ScaleToFit(width * conversion, height * conversion);

    document.Add(image);

    document.Close();
    pdfDoc.Close();

    var bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(temporaryPdfFromDbModifiedFullPath);

    File.Delete(temporaryPdfFromDbModifiedFullPath);
    File.Delete(temporaryPdfFromDbFullPath);

    return bytes;
}
```

**EDIT 2**

I achieved my goal without using temporary files and putting the image on all pages.

I hope it can be helpful for other people

```
public class ImageEventHandler : IEventHandler
{
    /// <summary>
    /// The img
    /// </summary>
    protected iText.Layout.Element.Image img;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the <see cref="ImageEventHandler"/> class.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="img">The img.</param>
    public ImageEventHandler(iText.Layout.Element.Image img)
    {
        this.img = img;
    }

    /// <summary>
    /// Hook for handling events.
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="event">the Event that needs to be processed</param>
    /// <remarks>
    /// Hook for handling events. Implementations can access the PdfDocument instance
    /// associated to the specified Event or, if available, the PdfPage instance.
    /// </remarks>
    public void HandleEvent(Event @event)
    {
        PdfDocumentEvent docEvent = (PdfDocumentEvent)@event;
        PdfDocument pdfDoc = docEvent.GetDocument();
        PdfPage page = docEvent.GetPage();
        PdfCanvas aboveCanvas = new PdfCanvas(page.NewContentStreamAfter(), page.GetResources(), pdfDoc);
        iText.Kernel.Geom.Rectangle area = page.GetPageSize();
        new Canvas(aboveCanvas, area).Add(img);
    }
}

public static byte[] AddImageToDocument(byte[] pdfBytes, System.Drawing.Image sign, float x, float y, float width, float height, Logger logger = null, bool addImageOnEveryPage = false)
{
    ImageData data = ImageDataFactory.Create(sign, null, false);

    WriterProperties properties = new WriterProperties();
    properties.SetFullCompressionMode(true);

    MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

    PdfWriter pdfWriterForDestinationPdf = new PdfWriter(memoryStream, properties);
    pdfWriterForDestinationPdf.SetSmartMode(true);
    var full = pdfWriterForDestinationPdf.IsFullCompression();

    PdfReader pdfReaderForSourcePdf = new PdfReader(new MemoryStream(pdfBytes));

    PdfDocument newPdfDoc = new PdfDocument(pdfReaderForSourcePdf, pdfWriterForDestinationPdf);
    iText.Layout.Document newDocument = new iText.Layout.Document(newPdfDoc);

    iText.Layout.Element.Image image = new iText.Layout.Element.Image(data);

    float conversion = 1f / 0.352777778f;

    image.SetFixedPosition(x * conversion, y * conversion);
    image.ScaleToFit(width * conversion, height * conversion);

    if (addImageOnEveryPage)
    {
        ImageEventHandler handler = new ImageEventHandler(image);
        newPdfDoc.AddEventHandler(PdfDocumentEvent.END_PAGE, handler);
    }
    else
        newDocument.Add(image);

    newDocument.Close();

    newPdfDoc.Close();

    return memoryStream.ToArray();
}
```

Thanks in advance,
Claudio

Comment: *"I was able to achieve the goal but only on the first page and not operating in memory; I create temporary files which I then delete."* - Where you now use file names, you often alternatively can use `Stream`s, in particular `MemoryStream`s. That should allow you to not have to use temporary files.